# Getting error after updating "kartik-v/yii2-detail-view" from "v1.7.6 to "v1.7.7

Tags: php, yii2, php-7.2, kartik-v

I am getting error in Yii2 after updating  "kartik-v/yii2-detail-view" from v1.7.6 to v1.7.7

```
Undefined class constant 'self::BS_PANEL'
```

And unable to find the solution for it. Do someone face the similar issue

update above using composer.

Composer file content

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "2.0.13",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "2.1.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datetimepicker": "^1.4",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "3.36.9",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-growl": "v1.1.1",
        "kartik-v/yii2-detail-view": "v1.7.7",
        "ckeditor/ckeditor": "dev-full/4.7.x as 4.7.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav": "v1.0.0",
        "dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset": "2.4.4",
        "kartik-v/yii2-date-range": "1.6.8",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput": "1.0.5",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-activeform": "v1.4.8",
        "linslin/yii2-curl": "1.2.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "v1.4.3",       
        "vova07/yii2-imperavi-widget": "2.0.2",
        "yiidoc/yii2-redactor": "2.0.1",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "6.0.5",
        "yii2tech/csv-grid": "1.0.1",
         "predis/predis": "1.1.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",

        "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "fxp-asset":{
            "installer-paths": {
                "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
                "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above is the content for composer using which i update kartik plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running an outdated version of `krajee-base`.

See [this.](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-activeform/issues/114) Different error but more than likely the same cause.

> kartik-v commented 20 days ago
>
> • Update packages via composer. You do not seem to have latest release of dependencies like yii2-krajee-base.

Remove `"kartik-v/yii2-detail-view": "v1.7.7",` in `composer.json` and replace with

```
"kartik-v/yii2-detail-view": "dev-master"
```

Then run composer install and composer update.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
"kartik-v/yii2-detail-view": "@dev"
```

Instead of

```
"kartik-v/yii2-detail-view": "v1.7.7",
```

I think it will help you.

Comment: It will change the latest update fo view detail
 package   yii2-detail-view
 author    Kartik Visweswaran <kartikv2@gmail.com>
 version   1.8.2